# Neural network sometimes outputs wrong values, like 1/10 times

Tags: neural-network

My neural network (1 inputs layer with 2 neurons, 1 hidden layer with 2 neurons and 1 output layer with 1 neuron), used for simple XOR problem, outputs correct values (over 0.9 value for [0, 1] and [1, 0] and under 0.05 for the rest) but sometimes, like 1/10 times, it outputs either ~0.5 for all or 0.6 for desired and 0.4 for wrong outputs. Wrong outputs exist even if it's learning for a , let's say, couple of minutes. I use learning rate = 0.1, I tried 0.01 and 1, too, and it didn't change too much.. I also use backpropagation to learn the nn.  My question is: is it normal behaviour or something is wrong with my nn? I know you can't say too much without code, but I'd like just to ask whether it's common behaviour.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sometimes'? Do you mean, without changing the weights of the network it sometimes outputs different results? Or do you mean after training the nn, it sometimes outputs different results? Can you share your weights, since there aren't to many in your network?

Comment: I'm so sorry for so late reply. I meant that I firstly set the weights randomly and I think the nn sometimes outputs wrong numbers because of that. And I also don't use the same weights, I always start the program again, so the weights are always different at start and end. Now, I'd like to know where to stop and to continue learning, to make the nn undependent from the first randomly set weights (if it actually causes the problem). Have you any idea how to achieve that? I googled a bit, but it seems I didn't found pleased results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In such an easy case the networks final state after training should be fairly consistent. The issue is a lot of things might have gone wrong. Without the code a lot of questions come to my mind about your training data, your initial weight setting, does the outcome change over training time, again an example of your final weights ...